# Cleaning up link-only answers to Wikipedia

Tags: discussion, downvotes, link-only-answers, vote-to-delete, clean-up

I was doing some research for links to Wikipedia on Stack Overflow and found many link-only answers and answers of low quality.

A lot of are [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes) (approx. 13k), most have a few [up-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=5&tab=Relevance&q=https%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2f%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a1) (approx. 27k), but many have [zero votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F+is%3Aanswer+score%3A0) (approx. 13k) or even [down-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F+is%3Aanswer+score%3A..-1) (approx. 1k). Please note, however, that not all answers which include a Wikipedia link are link-only answers, but many are.

I think we should take care of those and flag/delete/improve the answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F+is%3Aanswer

Comment: As you say yourself, the queries return too many results. So the numbers you list are useless, and manually checking tens of thousands of answers to see which ones are actually link-only is... subobtimal.

Comment: consider tweaking [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527543/find-some-link-mostly-answers-that-are-positively-received?MaxAnswerLength=512&MinScore=10&MaxBodyLengthWithoutUrl=29) for finding troublesome answers (MinScore parameter in there may be irrelevant though)

Comment: But why not starting to clean up?

Comment: Because it's the same as telling people to clean up [tag:php] or [tag:android] posts... *all* of them. Unless there's a more usable search query to efficiently clean up them, I don't think it's worthy enough to do mass cleanup like this (not to mention we already have a shortage of users to clean up the rest of the posts...)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRVIc.jpg

Comment: Honestly, you guys are taking this "link only" answer crusade way too far.  Why delete what may be the only answer to someone's question out of a misguided sense of purity?  If it bugs you so much, why not expand it into a non-"link only" answer and actually do some good?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But why not starting to clean up?

Counter-question: *why* start to clean-up? Why would this be a good use of our time?

If you come across low-quality, link-only answers like this in your regular travels through the site, then definitely do flag them so that they can be cleaned up (or, if you like, edit them yourself to flesh out the answer).

On the other hand, setting out with the express purpose of looking for them, armed with inexact and highly noisy queries, is not an especially good use of anyone's time. We generally want to focus our garbage-collection efforts on the garbage that is in front of people's faces. This maximizes the impact.

Case in point: your search string above found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371333/very-strange-javascript-error) at the very top of the list. Hmm, yup, I spy a low-quality, link-only answer to Wikipedia. Not so good. Maybe that one should be deleted. But wait…the question is nearly 8 years old, yet at the time of this answer's composition, has only had 130 views. This is not high-visibility garbage, and it's not causing any clear harm. In fact, out of those 130 views, 6 people have upvoted that answer and *nobody* has downvoted it.

Don't mistake this for an argument that these are good answers. They aren't. But site standards were a bit different 8 years ago, and it isn't clear that we would really be improving things by searching out and deleting that answer.